# Update task tag in AppEngine Pull Queue

Tags: google-app-engine, pull-queue

My app is running with Java but I think this should apply to Python as well.

Basically what I would like to achieve is be able to modify existing tasks in the queue.

All our tasks are tagged with certain names to decide which provider will consume it. However, in some chances, one tag's provider is down, and in this case we would like other providers be able to pick up those long waiting tasks.

In order to do this, I have think about the way is if certain providers haven't polling from the server for a while (pre-defined threshold), then the server will goes into the queue and modify the task's tags to something else so that other providers can consume it.

But I think from the docs I can't find out a way to do this.

Can anyone give a hint or there will be some other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Updating a task's tag isn't supported.  You'd need to create a new task and delete the old one.